# Cannot access NotFiniteNumberException

Tags: asp.net-core

Hi all and sorry for this "silly" question:

I have cloned and trying to use [this library for fractions.](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9078/Fraction-class-in-C)

I have imported the Fraction.cs class and most of the code looks ok. The original library targets (if I understand correctly) .NET Framework 2.0. My Solution supposedely targets .NET Core 1.1. The only discrepancy is that I cannot access type `NotFiniteNumberException` like this:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Globalization;
.
.
.
public Int32 ToInt32()
{
    if (this.m_Denominator == 0)
    {
        throw new FractionException(string.Format("Cannot convert {0} to 
Int32",
IndeterminateTypeName(this.m_Numerator)),
new NotFiniteNumberException()); // Red squiggly line here
}
```

Any ideas why this does not work? From my research, `NotFiniteNumberException` IS part of the .NET Core 1.1. framework. Am I wrong?

Aside: Any idea why MS does not ship a proper Fraction Class in its frameworks?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: C# will never throw that exception, since it already allows infinite results and storing of same, so maybe just take it out?

Comment: Maybe. Is this the reason it throws a type not found error?

Comment: Could be, this page may shed more light on it http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpInfinity.aspx

Comment: @aggaton Got it! According to all this info, I think it is semantically wrong to add that test. I need some code refactoring. Persisting the values is another issue altogether. Thank you! Will you answer, or shall I give it a go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# will never throw that exception, since it already allows infinite results and storing of same, it should be taken out and the code should be refactored.